# Create (and make accessible) DBs to be accessed through API

Tags: database, data, cloud-storage

We produce regularly some data sets that might be interesting for the proper audience.

The DBs have some thousand enties and the entries have 15 fields in a tree form:

```
{
    "item": {
        "title": "typical item",
        "range": {
            "subtitle": "S",
            "ID": {
                "date": {
                    "Max": "0/0", ...
```

That is, all are like that. and no data set is tabular.

For the access management, I have [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/) in mind. It seems to provide a good management of users, restrictions and so on.

But where would be **a good place to upload the DBs?**

It would need to be some platform that's **easy to manage**.  It should not force you to buy additional services. It should be easy to predict and restrict the **cost**, maybe allow for the inclusion of some delay.

A direct access (even through some form of access management as mentioned above) is not possible, no matter how safe a suggestion appears. The DBs offered are a subset of our own, but have to be segregated from those in daily use.

Comment: To be honest, I am not really sure what you are asking.  But that is probably my fault, as I got up at 2a.m to drive friend to the airport, and have not slept since. Reading "`a good place to upload the DBs?`", I will ask if [DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) might help? Alternatively, you can create the DB and use tools (e.g MySql  workspace) to create scripts to generate the DB, and then share on DropBox, Google Docs, GitHub, torrent ... or, did I misunderstand?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)